# Problem checking the solution of an ode

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

I am doing an exercise, which asks to show that given a continuous function $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$, then

$$y(x):=\alpha+\int_{0}^x f(t)\sin(x-t) dt$$

is the particular solution of $y''+y=f$ verifying $y(0)=\alpha$ and $y'(0)=0$

---

***What I have***

It is obvious that $y(0)=\alpha$. Using that $\sin(x-t)=\sin(x)\cos(t)-\cos(x)\sin(t)$, and using differentiation under integral sign, I have

$$y'(x)=\cos(x)\int_0^x f(t)\cos(t)dt+\sin(x)\int_0^xf(t)\sin(t)dt$$

and substituting $x=0$ we get $y'(0)=0$.

However, here is my problem. When I compute $y''$, and I write $y''+y$, after the cancelations, I get

$$y''+y=f+\alpha$$

(That $\alpha$ coming from $y$ doesn't go away). What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The claim is wrong.

If $f(x)=0 \forall x$, then you get
$$y(x)= \alpha$$
which is NOT a solution to 
$$y''+y= f$$
for $\alpha \neq 0$.

**Also note** that if you keep $f$ unchanged, in the equality
$$y''+y=f$$
the LHS changes when you change $\alpha$, but the RHS does not.

Just look at the equality $y''+y=f$ for two distinct values of $\alpha$ and the same $f$, you'll see that they cannot both hold.

Comment: That's what I though, yes. So apparently, any $y$ that is a solution of $y''+y=f$ needs to verify that $y(0)=0$, right?  So the correct statement of the exercise would be $y(x):=\int_{0}^x f(t)\sin(x-t) dt$, with $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$?

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman Or maybe the claim should be $$y''+y=f+\alpha$$

Comment: The claim should be $y''+y=f$ but the $\alpha$ term in $y$ should actually be $\alpha g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is the solution to $y''+y=0,y(0)=1,y'(0)=0$ which is of course $\cos(x)$. This is just the usual decomposition of a solution into a homogeneous and particular solution, but where you've chosen the particular solution *especially* to satisfy zero initial data (so that in some sense "all of the initial data is in the homogeneous part").